# MobileFirst Runtime "Disappearing" in Bluemix Container

Tags: mobile, docker, containers, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobilefirst

I have successfully deployed the MobileFirst Platform to Bluemix a number of times.  I am able to create the container group for the operations console (MFP Server), and then push an app to this server.  From there, I am able to install and run the app on my physical devices (a few Apple devices and a couple of Android devices).  At this point every thing works fine.

However, after some period of inactivity (about one day), the MFP runtime is no longer available on the server.  I can still log into the operations console, but the runtime is missing.  FYI, I am using a Cloudant DB service.

One thing I have noticed is the container "Created" time is shorter than the time that has past since I actually created the container.  For example, I created a container 6 days ago, but the container shows (in the Bluemix console) that the container was created 4 days ago.  Is it possible the container is getting recreated, thus loosing connectivity to the DB, or otherwise corrupting the MFP runtime?

Comment: container instances of the group gets recreated only when the auto-recovery is enabled for the group when it was created. Group's instances gets recreated when it is not active for a certain time interval. 

It wouldn't have corrupted the MFP Runtime, but there is a suspiscion of problems the Cloudant DB connection from the MFP. Can you reach the Database and check if you have the runtime entries ?

Comment: Thanks, Dave.  I do have auto-recovery turned off (or, I should say, I am accepting the default which should be N).  I am able to go to the Cloudant Dashboard and see my admin and runtime DBs.

Comment: @ToddL, is this still an issue? Note a recent email by the bluemix team (you should have gotten it too) about moving to new architecture.

Comment: Idan, yes, still having this problem.  I have found restarting the container group from the command line usually helps.  Restating from the BMX dashboard does not seem to work.  Also, the other day I tried a restart and the container group got hung up in the shutting down stage.  Also, my analytics group got corrupted.  I had to delete both and rerun the scripts to reestablish the environment.  FYI, I saw an email that the new architecture wasn't quite ready.  Has this changed?

Comment: I believe so, some time has passed since but I don't follow that aspect of Bluemix/Foundation.